# Karate contains function throws false negatie

Tags: karate

I am doing  a match contains for a multi dimensional JSON array. I am matching the first index of this array to say my actual response should contain at least this one index object of the array (not showing my payload or POST endpoint because of proprietary reasons and blocking out some of the JSON values in the response). But this used to work and now it does not.

```
* def expectedResponse = """
{
    "AccountExecutive": "ACME",
     ...Deleteing most of the fields because proprietary
    "MarketId": "Some String",
    "SomeOtherFieldAtTheEndWhichIsNull": null
}
```

This Throws error

```
When method post
Then status 200
And match response contains expectedResponse
```

"actual response does not match expected"

when it totally does. The only difference is actual response has lots of blocks like the above.

Comment: voting to close as unclear since there is absolutely no way for anyone to understand let alone replicate this Globally Insightful rant - I'm sorry I mean question :)

Comment: Although I am not familiar with the framework in the question, it looks like this is too little data for anyone to recommend you anything specific. Consider making a [mcve] before the down/close votes start rolling in.

Answer (score 1):

> I am matching the first index of this array to say my actual response
>   should contain at least this one index object of the array

Based on that. Try `And match each response[*] contains expectedResponse`

It would be a lot easier to understand your concern if you provide us with the response data, after removing proprietary stuff